# Init Script Not Running On System Reboot/Shutdown

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redis, init

I have made a bash init script in file at `/etc/init.d/redis-snapshot`:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          redis-snapshot
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $syslog Stime redis-server
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $syslog $time redis-server
# Default-Start:     0 6
# Default-Stop:      2 3 4 5
# Short-Description: Backup redis data on system exit
# Description:       redis-snapshot is a simple bash script to dump redis data
#                    to disk whenever the system shuts down or reboots.
### END INIT INFO

# path to script log file
ACTIVITYLOG='/home/noman/Desktop/redis-snapshot.log'

# create/touch log file
touch $ACTIVITYLOG

# invoke the save command on redis-cli
# this will dump all in-memory data to disk
OUTPUT="$(redis-cli SAVE)"

echo -e "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')\tSnapshoting Redis Data To Disk" >> $ACTIVITYLOG
echo -e "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')\tRedis says $OUTPUT" >> $ACTIVITYLOG

# end - nothing to do
```

I am using the following command to make it run on system reboot and shutdown:

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-snapshot start 99 0 6 .
```

It does not work for some reason and I am clueless what to try next.

Any bright ideas?

Comment: Is that the right command for your distribution? Did that update the correct links in the `/etc/rc#.d` directories? Does your distribution use init scripts at this point? Or did it move to `upstart` or `systemd`?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am on Ubuntu 14. The command I executed does say proper links have been setup in rc dirs

Comment: Do you *see* the proper links? Doesn't Ubuntu 14 use `upstart` instead of `sysvinit`? So shouldn't you be using whatever the appropriate `upstart`-related command is instead of `update-rc.d`? (Or is `update-rc.d` correct for `upstart` also?)

Answer (score 0):

What is your underlying distro and release?
Try

`chkconfig --add redis-snapshot`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to specifically find out whether your script is run, you may try skipping output redirection to file, so you'd see it during boot-up or checking `/var/log/boot.log` after boot.

If the output is missing, then your script was not added to `/etc/rc#.d`.

An alternative method of running a script on startup (which I prefer) is via `/etc/rc.local`. E.g.:

```
bash /root/script.sh
exit 0
```